# xrandr list 0 provider

Tags: fedora, nvidia, xrandr, wine

Here is the problem :

```
$ xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 0
```

We were trying to launch a game with a guy from the support team and we tryied installing nvidia drivers by all means but couldn't do it. By trying to debug everything he made me do this command. He told me that it was very unsual and that it could be one of the main reason why I couldn't play certain games.

I'm running Fedora 32 on an ASUS ROG laptop. I have a GTX 1060 and an Intel i7 7th gen.
Secure boot is Disabled.
 If you could help me that would be really nice (couldn't find anything like that on google).

Comment: What happens when you run `xrandr --auto`?

Comment: I'm not sure what guide you followed, but the [NVIDIA arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) is a pretty good place to start. Maybe also look around for guides specific to fedora. I found one [here](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/)

Comment: $ xrandr --auto
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Comment: @smac89 i followed this and many other tutorial but everytime i get a black screen and i'm forced to boot in console mode to uninstall nvidia and reactivate nouveau